# Not able to save tablerate.csv

Tags: magento-1.8

Saving tablerate.csv file for tablerate shipping method returns "An error occurred while saving this configuration: Unable to list current working directory." error.

screenshot -

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a file permission issue; check the value of upload_tmp_dir in php.ini - you can echo this out in a quick test script using `echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');` - make sure your PHP scripts are able to read and write to that directory, and to access that directory.

Basically, PHP or Apache (depending on your setup) doesn't have file permissions to even list files in the directory it's trying to use. If you're on shared hosting, this can be challenging to fix - and you might just want to open up a ticket with your hosting provider in that case.

Comment: but i am having another magento setup where this one is setup. and i am able to save that file successfully there. if this is a problem with server configuration then tablerates.csv should not save with any magento setup configured on that server.

Comment: The error that you provided is a file system error. I know it seems odd if another Magento instance is able to work on the same server, but that error message is only generated when there's an issue opening a directory on the file system. Are both Magento installations running under the same account/user? Have you confirmed that the file ownership and permission settings are exactly the same between the two installations? If you find a difference - there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration settings for tablerates.csv make sure it is comma seperated fields & not tab seperated & check the columns are properly added in csv. It should work.

Comment: Bhavesh, i checked my csv file is a valid one. but cant see any setting in magento to change tab sep to comma sep. let me know where should i check this.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of Google results, this error is reported if you have run out of disk space.